# Interface in library, implementations in different apps, method call from library

Tags: java

I have an `interface method` in a library which is being called by a method in the same library. The implementations are in the applications which include the library. The implementations are different for every application. In order to call the `interface method`, the `calling method` must instantiate the `interface` with its implemented `class`. But since the `calling method` is in the library, it has no access to the classes in the applications. The `calling method` is started by a background service and not by the application.

The interface in the library:

```
public interface InterfaceA {
    void methodA();
}
```

The class in the application which implements the interface:

```
public class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
    @Override
    public void methodA() {
        // do something
    }
}
```

The method in the library which calls the interface method:

```
public void callInterface() {
    InterfaceA ia;
    ia.methodA(); // how to get this to work?
}
```

How do I call the `interface method` from the library without any access to the `interface` implementations in the applications? I cannot instantiate the interface from my library as the implementation classes are in the application which the library has no access to.

Comment: Either you missed that there is an implementation existing in the library OR the method "callInterface" is part of stateless implementation. In that case your implementation is passed in the method as input or using Generics. Could you please reveal more details about library class calling the method.

Comment: @shakeel No implementation exists in the library. That's the problem. The library class has no access to any of the implementation classes.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything to get it to work if you have an instance of the interface:

```
public void callInterface(InterfaceA ia) {
    ia.methodA();
}
```

And then add this parameter to the library methods which call this method, and so on. When applications call this method, they can pass their implementations.

Or if you really need to instantiate the interface inside the method, add another interface:

```
public void callInterface(Supplier<InterfaceA> iaSupplier) {
    InterfaceA ia = iaSupplier.get();
    ia.methodA();
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html.

> The calling method is started by a background service and not by the application.

And what starts the background service? You need to add some way for the application to pass the implementation to it.

Alternately, you could use SPI (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html) but it may be overkill.

Comment: The library class has no access to any of the implementation classes. Only to the interface.

Comment: And in both versions of `callInterface` here it doesn't need it.

Comment: The OS starts the service through a job scheduler. `callInterface` can only access `InterfaceA` not `ClassA`.

Comment: Then it's that background service which needs an implementation, not the library. From the question I assumed it was started in the context of some application; if "The OS starts the service through a job scheduler" then it looks more like its own application instead and so will need to provide the implementation (SPI won't help).

Comment: Of course, if you want to reuse an implementation from some other application in the service, you can extract that implementation into a separate library.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Is there a way to run the method without instantiating the interface. I have not been able to find out.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void callInterface() {
    InterfaceA ia;
    ia.methodA(); // how to get this to work?
}
```

Above should result in compilation problem.

The library function should take as parameter the Interface InterfaceA  in method as shown in another answer Or If it is a stateless implementation then pass it while using the Class that contain this method.